# Can't parse web.xml file in Java

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a web.xml file in Java using `org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser` but I don't get it.

The program is really simple:

```
public WebXml read() {
    WebXml webXml = new WebXml();

    WebXmlParser parser = new WebXmlParser(false, true, true);

    try (InputStream is = Reader.class.getResourceAsStream("/web.xml")) {
        boolean success = parser.parseWebXml(new InputSource(is), webXml, false);
        if (!success) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error parsing");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error reading", e);
    }

    return webXml;
}
```

The web.xml is in the project's root and it has a servlet defined:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demoServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.demo.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demoServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/demo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I try to parse the web.xml with the above snippet I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 4 column 24: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 24; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'.
```

I don't understand the error because IMHO the web.xml is correctly written.

I've prepared a sample project to show the error: https://github.com/itelleria/webxml-parser

I would appreciate any help with this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked whether `web.xml` is included in archive?

Comment: Yes, the `web.xml` file is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it worked with disabled validation

```
WebXmlParser parser = new WebXmlParser(false, false, true);
```

Comment: thanks for the update. I also got confused at what was the problem. Nice solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your change and as you say it works. The thing is that my github project is a demo to isolate the problem. Actually, in my real project I'm trying to read a web.xml which is inside WEB-INF and despite disabling validation it fails with another error. Moving the web.xml to classpath root it works... I wonder why I can't read the web.xml inside WEB-INF. I accept your answer because you have solved my original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of servlet or any tags you can use this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = docBuilder.parse("D:\\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\\demo-xml-parser\\src\\main\\resources\\web.xml");  // path of your testNgXml
    NodeList parameterNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("servlet");
    System.out.println(parameterNodes.getLength());
}
```

I have your project and trying to debug the problem, in the mean time you can use above mentioned method.
Please do not mind if it is not what you are looking for.
It is just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want to parse the whole `web.xml`file. I've thought about developing a parser using `DocumentBuilderFactory`, but before that I wanted to give another try to Tomcat's `WebXmlParser`.